# How can I return an archived readable stream in node.js without writing to filesystem?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to refactor my function to return a readable stream that I will pipe to http request module,
currently I'm returning the archived file location and creating a readstream from it:

```
const filepath = yield archive.archiveFilesAsTargz('path', 'name.tar.gz');

fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(request(options)).then(body =>{
        console.log(body);
    });
```

The flow I'm seeking is:

1. get a directory location as and archive it
2. get the archive as stream and return it (resolve it)
3. invoke the function and pipe the read stream to request

my function is as follows:

```
    exports.archiveFilesAsTargz = function (dest, archivedName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        const name = slugify(archivedName);
        const filePath = path.join(dest, name + '.tar.gz');
        const output = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
        const archive = archiver('tar', {
            gzip: true
        });

        archive.pipe(output);
        archive.directory(dest, name).finalize();
        output.on('close', ()=> resolve(filePath));
        archive.on('error' ,(err) => reject(err));
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so after another reading session and plays I solved it...

```
function archiveFilesAsTargz (dest, name) {
        const archive = archiver('tar', {
            gzip: true
        });
        return archive.directory(dest, name).finalize();
}
```

the following will return a readstream :

```
archive.directory(dest, name).finalize();
```

so using it a follows worked great for me

```
const pack = archiveFilesAsTargz(zippath, 'liron');

pack.pipe(request(options)).then(body =>{
        console.log(body);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```